# What is the difference between preferences of the producer vs the consumer?

Tags: microeconomics, preferences, producer-theory

The book I am working with (Rubinstein) states that in the case of the profit-maximizing producer, preferences are linear and the constraint is a convex set. Meanwhile, in the consumer model, preferences are convex and the constraint is a linear inequality.

I do understand the part of the consumer model, but I do not understand why he says that preferences of the producer are linear. How is it related to the isoquants?

Comment: Profits are a linear function of production plans.

Comment: The quote appears at the end of the 5th section of chapter 7 (Production) of Rubinstein's Lecture Notes in Microeconomic Theory. The first five sections of this chapter explain in detail how this claim is derived. Have you read these sections?